# How safe is to use card.io library?

Tags: android, card.io

Just thinking to integrate card.io scanning library to our Android App, though Uber, Eat24, Grab Hub uses the same library for scanning the card but just want to make sure how safe is to use the library??
Does this library captures or saves the card information anywhere?

Comment: _Uber, Eat24, Grab Hub uses the same library_ Is that not significant for you?

Comment: What do they use right now?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, the library is open source so everyone can check the code. Check the code here: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK

The library don't store any data related to the credit cards so feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks. @Sandro Machado